# Realm deleted objects strategy and notifications

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa, realm

It's not an issue, but rather just a general question on how realm collection change notifications are dispatched if changes happen in background thread.

So there is a scenario (in Realm Cocoa):

1. `RLMResults` of objects of class `Foo: RLMObject` is fetched from default realm. The list is then transformed into array `[Foo]` and saved as variable in view controller (does not matter)
2. Table displays that list of foo objects
3. Some objects are deleted on background thread
4. User scrolls the table view, cell is reused, object from array at index x is accessed, but it was deleted on background thread and crash happens, because `object was deleted or invalidated`. As expected.

To solve that we could use collection notifications and refresh the list when changes occur. As I tried everything works as expected, but isn't it possible that dispatch of cell reuse will occur before notification is dispatched on main thread so that cell setup method will be using invalidated object?

Just tried to explain the question as detailed as possible.

Mainly the question is about situation(s) when data sync with server (not using Realm's mobile platform) is happening on background thread and views, whether they're table cells or any other views, are holding references to could-be-deleted objects. Is it a good practice to check if object was invalidated when trying to do something with the object because it could be deleted on background thread.

I see a couple of solutions:

- each time accessing reference of `RLMObject` subclass object check if it is not invalidated
- wrap the object into view model (leaving all the good parts of self-updating model features) which then leaves with another two solutions when trying to change the model:

  - save object id in view model so that when trying to change it would be possible to fetch object again
  - have a reference to the object itself having the same problems as the first point

What are the suggestions for this?

EDIT:

Using `Results` and `List` sometimes not really possible if the object `Foo` is complicated. For example when opening details screen of Foo table view with lots of different cells accessing properties of `Foo` class' object. So on notification about deleted object screen could be dismissed, but as user scrolls isn't it possible that cell could be accessing invalidated object?

Maybe the question is just stupid, over engineered about raise conditions, but I'm curious if it's possible that dispatches on main thread will occur something like: `object becomes invalidated (I don't know how that happens in realm internally>` then `some code which access that object` then `notification about invalidated object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The list is then transformed into array [Foo] and saved as variable in view controller (does not matter)

Why do you do this? This forces every object in the `Results` to be materialized into memory, with (potentially expensive) Swift-level object accessors to be created and some db data read from disk. All Realm collections conform to the Swift standard library's `CollectionType` protocol, meaning that it behaves like other collections such as `Array` already. Copying out all of the `Results` elements into an `Array` will also mean that the array will quickly get out of sync with its underlying data, since `Array` isn't auto-updating unlike `Results`.

This easily explains why some of the Realm objects that you copy into the `Array` are then deleted, which causes the objects to become invalidated, meaning that any subsequent access is a violation of Realm's API.

Long story short, don't copy `Results`, `List` or any other Realm collection into an `Array`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I know how Realm works as it uses mmap, but sometimes table view is displaying single object, see EDIT of the question.

Comment: I've read your edit, and I still don't see why you prefer copying all the data out of the `List` or `Results` helps when `Foo` is complicated.

Comment: I'm not talking about the list, I'm talking about a single `Foo` object display in table view. Like if table source file has reference to single `Foo` object and displays it's details in rows.

Comment: If you're talking about a single `Foo` object, why does it matter if the object is stored in a `List`, `Results` or `Array`?

Comment: At this point I rather talking about a single reference to single object in screen (i.e details screen). The ultimate question is about the sequence of dispatches (at the end of the question)

Comment: To your question about whether or not the main thread may update before the notification is dispatched, the answer there is a strict no, since `Realm.refresh()` forces notifications to be invoked synchronously, the same thing happens when `Realm.autorefresh` is enabled, and `Realm.beginWrite()`/`Realm.write(...)` implicitly calls `refresh()` so the same thing goes there.

Comment: Great, that's probably all I needed. Thanks